# Nested loops, list got no value

Tags: perl, loops, nested

I'm trying to implement a solution where the all the elements one by one of `list1` are compared against all elements of `list2`.

Elements of list 1:

```
3155
3122
3188
```

Elements of list 2:

```
3155785
458999
742199
315520
31550638
4289965
31221478
1478596
3122145
31889963
31889801
```

If an element in ***list 1*** matches an element in ***list 2***

E.g. `3155` to `3155785` or to `315520`, the element of ***list 1*** is printed into STDOUT.

```
$i=0;
$j=0;
foreach(@list1)
{
 foreach(@list2)
 {
    if($list1[$i]=~/$list2[$j]/)
    {
        print $list1[$i];
        last;
    }

    $j++;
 }

$i++;
}
```

Nothing is printed into `STDOUT`

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: You're using for loops in a funny way: You iterate the elements but use ‘homegrown’ indices to access them. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Have a read of https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html and learn about Hashes.  Whenever you think set membership, uniqueness, counting, etc. think hash.  It is a simple task in perl to use a hash, but I recommend you learn about it and implement the solution yourself.

Comment: Another thing is if you see yourself wanting to use `$i` and `$j` in your code and incrementing...that is a c style and is prone to bugs in edge cases.  A more perlish way would be to iterate over the list items themselves, as in `for my $book ( @library ) { print "Go read $book\n"; }`

Answer (score 1):

Backwards.

```
$list1[$i] =~ /$list2[$j]/
```

should be

```
$list2[$j] =~ /$list1[$i]/
```

Better yet, we could remove the assumption that the inputs will only be ASCII digits by using

```
$list2[$j] =~ /\Q$list1[$i]\E/
```

Cleaned up:

```
for my $item1 (@items1) {
   for my $item2 (@items2) {
      if ($item2 =~ /\Q$item1\E/) {
         say $item1;
         last;
      }
   }
}
```

Starting a regex match is relatively expensive, so the following can save time:

```
my $items2 = join "\0", @items2;  # Assumes NUL will never be any element of @items1.
for my $item1 (@items1) {
   say $item1 if $items2 =~ /\Q$item1\E/;
}
```